# javascript fade in fade out doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why my javascript doesn't work AS IT IS? Below is the code:

```
function load(){
    function fadein(){
        var op = document.getElementsByClassName("load_1")[0]
        op.style.opacity = 0;
        function animate(){
            if ((op.style.opacity = op.style.opacity + 0.01) < 1){
                alert("Hello")
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }
        }
        animate()
    }
    fadein()
}

load()
```

Comment: what is the function requestAnimationFrame ? are you able to hit the alert??

Comment: requestAnimationFrame what this function must do? i tested this script and it gives alert but i have no idea what is requestAnimationFrame. please give us more information

Comment: When do you call load - before or after DOM ready? style.opacity is probably a string, you need to convert it to float before adding 0.1, also, requestAnimationFrame does not guarantee a framerate, so better replace + 0.1 with a calculation based on timestamp

Comment: can you use jquery ?

Comment: What is the significance of this line  if ((op.style.opacity = op.style.opacity + 0.01) < 1)?

Comment: @le_m true i just tested it

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("pln")[0].style.opacity=1` then `document.getElementsByClassName("pln")[0].style.opacity+0.01` 
return `10.01`

Comment: reauestAnimationFrame is the correct way to recursively queue functions which perform some animation. At a glance I'm guessing le_m is right and you need to parse to a float.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you wanted it to work exactly the way it so, so I apologise if my suggestions are going a bit overboard, but I couldn't get it to work the way you have it for the below reasons:

1. Nesting the function is not a good practice at least in JavaScript in my opinion as it will many times cause it to not work, as seems to be doing in your case. Tha being said, you can define them separately and call them inside your load function.
2. the definition of the var op will work better if it is declared outside so it is a shared variable. Otherwise I would suggest passing it as argument between the functions. Depends really on what you are aiming for later on, but the way it is at the moment I noticed that it prevents the other function from seeing it sometimes
3. Lastly, but possibly most importantly, op.style.opacity is not a number. you can pass a number directly to it, but adding a number to it won't work, as it gets parsed to string to become CSS.

Find below a suggestion code. It has multiple changes but hopefully not too many as you wished for.

```
 var op = document.getElementsByClassName("load_1")[0];
 load();
 function load(){
     fadein();
     animate();
 }
 function animate(){
      var opac = parseFloat(op.style.opacity);
      opac = opac+0.1;
      op.style.opacity = opac;
      if ((op.style.opacity) < 1){
           alert("Hello");
           requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
}
function fadein(){
     op.style.opacity = 0.1;
}
```